# background-img problem in tailwindcss path is not correct

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6y6W.png) earlier my website looks like this now i want instead of blue color i want an img present in assets now this not working why?
[structure of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQjom.png)use this image for checking structure of folder for path of the img
my code

````
 <div className="flex flex-row w-2/3 bg-url('../assets/background.jpg') h-screen " >
         {/*   <img>
            </img>*
            
           
            <div className=" flex justify-center">
                <h1>enter</h1>
                <h1 className="text-3xl">hiiii</h1>
                <div className="shadow "></div>
    
        </div>
``` my image is not showing 

i change the path of the img but showing nothing
````

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 things:

1. your image should be in public
2. url should not have "..", use public folder as root.

   bg-[url('/background.jpg')] if you put in public folder

   bg-[url('/assets/background.jpg')] if you create assets folder in public

Hope that help.

Comment: still not working i make a folder img in public folder and used    <div className="flex flex-row w-2/3 bg-url('/img/background.jpg') h-screen " > and not working

Comment: It should be bg-[url('/img/background.jpg')]"

Comment: <div className="flex flex-row w-2/3 bg-[url('/img/background.jpg')] h-screen " >  now it is same like that only and showing this error   ERROR in ./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css) 5:36-83
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/img/background.jpg' in 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\navieo\src'

Comment: Error say that file does not exist. Make sure that folder is called img in public. If that does not work try to create img folder with image in src.